# passing html tags from a json feed

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm getting a json feed that returns content with HTML tags (as it is generated from a CMS). The json feed its self is fine, but it renders the html tags within the content like so:

```
<p>First para</p><p>Second para</p>
```

I would like it to render the formatted html tags like so:

First para

Second para

I have tried using php 'html_entity_decode' and 'htmlentities' to manipulate the content before returning the json to no avail.

I'm using jquery templating to render the json data like so:

```
var markup = '<h5>${title}</h5><p>${date}</p>${content}';
```

Any ideas as to what I'm missing should I formatting $content as an jquery .html() object for instance ?

EDIT: here is the templating code - I tried .html() within it but only got errors?

```
    function getArticle(type, id) { 
    $.getJSON("http://www.jsonexample.com/api/?type="+ type +"&aid="+ id +"", function(json) {     
       var markup = '<h5>${title}</h5><p>${date}</p>${content}';
       $.template( "articleTpl", markup );     
       $.tmpl( "articleTpl", json ).appendTo('#article');   
     }); 
}
```

**It seems this works although in beta Notice the {{html content}}:**

```
var markup = '<h5>${title}</h5><p>${date}</p>{{html content}}';
```

What are peoples views on using this in an app?

Comment: show your code for rendering template.

Comment: Code updated ravi - any ideas on how to wrap $content with the .html() method?

Answer (score 2):

I am not completely sure I understand your question - but if you get passed JSON that contains HTML tags and want to display them in your page, use the .html(value) function in jQuery.

Could you share the code you are currently trying to do this with?

Here's a jsfiddle illustrating what (I think) is your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/V33Zv/6/

1) Pass proper tags

2) Use the .html(string) function

Comment: Hey there - I took a look at you jsfiddle link (thanks), the data in the json feed in as per html1 but i want it to render as html and not display the <p> tag its self.

Comment: Yes, that is what I did with the fiddle, but it was a bit unclear. I've updated it to a clearer example: http://jsfiddle.net/V33Zv/6/

Comment: That is perfect - the only thing i'm unsure of is how to get the ${content} data into a variable to apply .html() onto and then return it to the tempalte (all atempts have failed)? I understand perfectly if it were content from a page element - any advice?

Comment: Sorry, I never use jQuery templates. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
function getArticle(type, id) { 
    $.getJSON("http://www.jsonexample.com/api/?type="+ type +"&aid="+ id +"", function(json) {     
       var markup = '<h5>${title}</h5><p>${date}</p>${content}';
      $.template( "articleTpl", $(markup).html() ); // here the changes. 
       $.tmpl( "articleTpl", json ).appendTo('#article');   
     });
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this - but the result only partially loads the template. Do you have any views on using {{html content}}